# Getting [eslint] 'value' is assigned a value but never used when using joi validation for vue.js fullstack application

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, eslint, joi

I am trying to add validation for the request payload before it reaches to my controller using Joi validator. I doing everything according to joi documentation but still getting this error which causes my nodemon server to crash-

Error - [eslint] 'value' is assigned a value but never used.

`

```
const joi = require('joi')    
module.exports = {
  register (req, res, next) {
    const schema = {
      email: joi.string().email(),
      password: joi.string().password()
    }
    const { error, value } = joi.validate(req.body, schema)

    if (error) {
      switch (error.details[0].context.key) {
        case 'email':
          res.status(400).send({
            error: 'You must provide a valid email address'
          })
          break
        case 'password':
          res.status(400).send({
            error: 'You must provide a valid password'
          })
          break
        default:
          res.status(400).send({
            error: 'Invalid information provided'
          })
      }
    } else {
      next()
    }
  }
}
```

`

Please help on how to solve the issue?

Comment: I don't know about joi, but could you try this:
const { error, _value } = joi.validate(req.body, schema)

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: I'm guessing the req.body contains some code you wrote, right ? If so, try to look for an unused variable named 'value' in that code, and rename it '_value'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have an eslint setting to cause errors under certain rules.  Namely, a rule you have set to error out on is "no-unused-vars".  You are destructuring the validation method, and peeling out the `error` and `value` keys, while also creating variables themselves.  But, you aren't actually using `value` anywhere.  Why don't you try just doing:
`const { error } = joi.validate(req.body, schema)`

That should stop the eslint error.